# How to find the position of the user, based on earnings, but without listing all users into Memory

Tags: python, optimization

I have 200k users in database. I want to know the given user's position depending on his earnings, but without listing all the 200k users (explodes the memory of my small laptop)

So, given 200k users, and each users has an earning rank. My calculation so far was very simple:

```
all_users = User.objects.order_by('-lifetime_earnings')
try:
    user_rank = list(all_users.values_list('id', flat=True)).index(given_user_id)
    # because list is 0-based
    user_rank += 1
except ValueError:
    user_rank = 1
```

list all 200k users sorted by rank and get the index of the given user. But this is not working anymore, because of RAM and obviously also not efficient way.

Comment: Can you give some more context? `User.objects.order_by('-lifetime_earnings')` what does this return? Is it a list or a generator?  What does `all_users.values_list('id', flat=True)` return?

Comment: Is there a way to retreive the users from db with just the fields `id` and `lifetime_earnings`? If yes, then that would reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: Also, if you want to find out the rank of multiple users, its better to create a hashmap of <userId> vs <rank> so that its O(1) to get the rank of a user. `list.index()` is O(n).

Comment: From your statement I think you are using django, If so you can just do this:
user = User.object.get(id=user_id)
rank = User.object.filter(lifetime_earnings__lte=user.lifetime_earnings).count()

Comment: It's known bottleneck of django (both time and memory) -- creating an object for every table db row.